# Stripe checkout unable to access my django apps success page on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, stripe-payments

I am a relatively inexperienced python/django programmer and have run into a issue that i am unable to resolve on my own, inspite of searching around for help. English is not my first language so please do not mind language related errors in my attempt to explain my problem.

My django 3.2 App uses stripe checkout for payment. While in development on my local machine, i could process payment and return to my apps success page, but after i deployed it to heroku, it processes the payment but wont return to my apps success page. I have installed the corsheaders package and have tried all the possible settings suggested here on stackoverflow and elsewhere. I am stating my settings below and also the stripe checkout views code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

all the relevant settings are as under

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 3rd party
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'cloudinary',
    'storages',

    # local
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'cart.apps.CartConfig',
    'payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
    'order.apps.OrderConfig',
    'setmenu.apps.SetmenuConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

core.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('api.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='carturls')),
    path('setmenu/', include('setmenu.urls', namespace='setmenu')),
    path('orders/', include('order.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
    path('', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
]
```

payment urls.py

```
app_name = 'payment'

urlpatterns = [
    path('process/', login_required(views.payment_process), name='process'),
    path('done/', views.payment_done, name='done'),
    path('canceled/', views.payment_canceled, name='canceled'),
    path('webhook/', views.webhook, name='webhook')
]
```

Payment apps view that processes payment

```
def payment_process(request):
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id')
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    total_cost = int(order.get_total_amount() * 100)

    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        line_items=[{
            'price_data': {
                'currency': 'inr',
                'product_data': {
                    'name': f'Order number {order_id}',
                },
                'unit_amount': f'{total_cost}',
            },
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url='https://myappname.herokuapp.com/payment/done',
        cancel_url='https://myappname.herokuapp.com/payment/canceled',
    )
    return redirect(session.url, code=303)
```

even if i put a done/ it doesnt redirect. The below success urls work though and i am redirect to my home page and the admin page respectively.

success_url='https://myappname.herokuapp.com'
and
success_url='https://myappname.herokuapp.com/admin'

But ofcourse, ideally it has to return to the specific success page. The fact that it successfully redirects to https://myappname.herokuapp.com/admin, bothers me even more as to why it wont go to https://myappname.herokuapp.com/payment/done

I have tried to discard the payment urls and dump the payment routes in the core urls thinking that its not accessing custom namespaced urls, but that too did not work.

Please do point me to the right direction. I am inclined to think that my Cors settings are not right but then i have allowed all hosts and cors_origin_allow_all is true.The corsheaders middleware is also at the top as suggested but yet its not redirecting from stripe. So i feel like i have hit a wall.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: When you said `it doesn't redirect` what do you have after you complete the checkout in the browser? Did you track if your page payment/done is accessible or if it tries to load ? Can you post some screenshots or a GIF/video that demonstrates the issue ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. After the payment is processed, it tries to reach myappname.herokuapp.com/payment/done but after a few seconds I get a page with the aforementioned url that displays error which says - An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Check logs for details. The status code in log is 301

Comment: Hi @susdud did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same thing and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on the topic.

Comment: @econobro I finally found out that once it redirected to the success page, it had to do a RabbitMQ task but I had not setup rabbitmq on heroku and as such it crashed. Quite embarrassing but it was redirecting alright  from stripe. Do check your view, I am sure you will find your bug.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @susdud . Mine is looking more like a networking issue with my GoDaddy-hosted domain firewalling the Stripe IPs but hoping my DNS update yesterday propagates and resolves the issue. However, I'll also check to make sure I don't have any other views running. Thanks!